# How to set The Border for Entire Cells in Jtable in Netbeans Using Swings

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have added a JTable and Set Border for Table

But i also want to add the borders for entire cells inside Table... I tried several ways but couldn't solve it... Can anyone help me in this
!

Comment: This depends.  You can change the grid color via the `JTable`. Otherwise you need to supply a custom `TableCellRenderer` which is capable of providing the look and feel your after. See [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi , I Have tried this code and its working which adds outside Border to Table 'jTable1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));' But i want border for all rows and colums (Cells) inside the table... A sample could be appreciated...